# How to make several similar properties call one generic one

Tags: vb.net, properties

I'm wondering if it's possible in VB.NET to make similar properties call one generic one?
A sentence doesn't explain it well so here's a code example.

I have a bit field defined like this:

```
<Flags()> _
Enum E_Operation As Integer
    Upload = 1
    Download = 2
    Overwrite = 4
    etc...
End Enum
```

Now my class has one property per bit in the bit field. Each property just returns the value or sets the corresponding flag. e.g.

```
Public Property IsUpload() As Boolean
Get
    Return ((Operation And E_Operation.Upload) = E_Operation.Upload)
End Get
Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
    SetBit(E_Operation.Upload, value)
End Set
End Property
```

Now I have quite a lot of properties and I would like to simplify them (ideally just one line) by calling a generic property with the bit number to Set or Get.

```
Public Property IsUpload() As Boolean
    GenericProperty(E_Operation.Upload)
End Property
```

Is there any way to achieve this in VB.NET?

Comment: {offtopic} Are you sure none of the answers to your other questions are acceptable?

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow and I only found out recently that it was good practice to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the enumeration a parameter in a private property:

```
Private Property OperationFlag(Flag As E_Operation) As Boolean 
    Get 
        Return ((Operation And Flag) = Flag) 
    End Get 
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean) 
        Operation = (Operation And Not Flag) Or (value And Flag)
    End Set 
End Property
```

And make a public property wrapper:

```
Public Property IsUpload As Boolean
    Get
        Return OperationFlag(E_Operation.Upload)
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        OperationFlag(E_Operation.Upload) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: And as Bala R stated above, please press the tick next to the answers that solve your questions.  Please go back through your previous questions (see your profile page) and do the same.  You'll find people unwilling to help you if you don't acknowledge their time taken to assist you.

Comment: Thanks Hand-E-Food, that's exactly what I did in my code but what I want is some "magic" syntax that will allow me to write each property in one line (i.e. call the generic property for bit Upload). And yes I've started to go through my previous questions.

Comment: I'd just leave it at the first one, maybe call it OperationFlagSet, and not bother with the named properties.  Don't do it if you ever contemplate moving to C#, it doesn't support indexed properties well.  The setter needs a bug fix.

Comment: @JBB: Good to hear!  I see what you're asking now, but properties don't work that way unfortunately.  It may suit you better to make `OperationFlag` a public property and call that instead of `IsUpload`, etc.